# Automatic watermarking - Folder Action

Tags: macos, bash, imagemagick, applescript

I have a bash script, which automatically watermarks every image in a folder.

```
WATERMARK="$HOME/Dropbox/logo_bw.png"
if [ ! -e "watermarked_tmp" ]
then
mkdir watermarked_tmp
fi
#loop inside all the images in folder
for image in *.jpg *.JPG *.jpeg *.JPEG *.png *.PNG
do
if [ ! -e "$image" ] # Check if file exists.
then
continue
fi
#Retrieve size of the image and divide the lenght by 2
size=`identify -format %[fx:w/4,279] $image`
#Apply the watermark and create a new image in the "watermarked" subfolder
composite  -dissolve 10% -quality 100 -gravity SouthEast -background none \( $WATERMARK -geometry ${size} \) ${image} watermarked_tmp/${image}
done
```

I want to create a Folder Action from this code with Automator. Anyone know how to pass current directory and their files? I tried to do, but it fails at the line `for image in *.jpg *.JPG *.jpeg *.JPEG *.png *.PNG`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set pass input to as arguments and use a for loop like `for f; do`:

```
watermark=~/a.png
d=~/watermarked_temp
mkdir -p $d
shopt -s nocasematch
for f; do
  [[ $f =~ .*\.(jpe?g|png)$ ]] || continue
  target="$d/${f##*/}"
  size=$(identify -format '%[fx:w/4,279]' "$f")
  composite -dissolve 10% -gravity SouthEast\
  \( $watermark -geometry $size \) "$f" -quality 100 "$target"
done
```

Comment: thank you for the complete script. It is executes without problem, but it only creates the watermarked_temp folder. No watermarked images inside.

Comment: You're right, I edited the script. You might also need to use the full paths for `identify` and `compose`.

Comment: Yes, it's working now. :) One more question: is there any way to make watermarked_temp directory in the current directory?

Comment: If you mean the directory the currently processed image is in, you can use something like `d="${f%/*}/watermarked_temp"; mkdir -p "$d"; target="$d/${f##*/}"`.

Comment: Lauri, if you reading this. How it is possible to add to directory name date+hour+minute and make only one directory /session? http://d.pr/n/tbx4 - this creates new folder every minute, if the FA is running.

Comment: What do you mean by session? You could create one directory per day with something like `shopt -s nullglob; a=("${f%/*}/wm_$(date +%Y_%m_%d)"*); [[ $a ]] && d=${a[0]} || d="${f%/*}/wm_$(date +%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M)"`.